# What is a very comprehensive syntax structure?

Tags: grammar, syntax

the syntax is S V O, 
one can expand this to include phrases about time and place:
S t p V O.

What else can be this SVO structure expanded with?
How would a maximal structure look like that incorporates all or almost all phrases possible?

Comment: Would like to hear about the purpose of the question so that discussion may be easier. 
Otherwise it sounds like a math question. (:

Comment: http://eastasiastudent.net/china/mandarin/word-order

Comment: I have confidence building simple sentences in Chinese, like those whch only are made of S V O.
for instance: 
可爱的熟女(S) 亲吻了(V) 爱豆腐的青蛙 (O) 
the sentence does not make much sense, but it is grammatically correct, 
i could expand this sentence for a time and place phrase:
可爱的熟女(S) 每天(timePhr.) 在井上(PlacePhr.) 亲吻了(V) 爱豆腐的青蛙 (O)
so far i am confident, but there exist much more phrases than s,v,o,time and place and i am absolutely clueless where to put them within the sentence structure.

Answer (score 1):

- You could assemble Chinese as well as English.
- Pure SVO structure.

  1. 淑女 亲吻着 青蛙。
  2. 可爱的淑女 偷偷地亲吻着 绿色的青蛙。
  3. 蹲在湖边的可爱的淑女 略带羞涩地偷偷地轻吻着 站在荷叶上的绿色的青蛙。
  4. 一位蹲在湖边的可爱的淑女 低着头略带羞涩地偷偷地轻吻着 一只站在荷叶上的绿色的青蛙。
- Then add more parts.

  1. 在一个温暖的午后 一位蹲在湖边的可爱的淑女 低着头略带羞涩地偷偷地轻吻着 一只站在荷叶上的绿色的青蛙。
  2. 在一个温暖的午后 一位蹲在湖边的可爱的淑女 穿着连衣裙 头上戴着金灿灿的小皇冠 手上拿着一朵花 低着头略带羞涩地偷偷地轻吻着 一只站在荷叶上的绿色的青蛙。
- More parts with the help of comma and dash in Chinese.

  1. 在一个温暖的午后，蝴蝶在风中翩翩起舞， 一位蹲在湖边的可爱的淑女 穿着连衣裙 头上戴着金灿灿的小皇冠 手上拿着一朵花，在左右旁顾无人以后， 低着头略带羞涩地偷偷地轻吻着 一只站在荷叶上的绿色的——其实我们都知道那是一只被施展了魔法的，从一位英俊王子变成的——青蛙。
- If I want, I could write a much longger one. :)

Answer (score -1):

I'll add a bit more into your formula:

S + time + at... + from... + with(someone) + with/using(tool) + to/for(someone) + [把(O)] + V + 了/过/着 + O + 了 + 吗/呢/吧/啊

In Chinese:

主 + 时 + 在 + 从 + 跟/和 + 用/坐 + 给 + [把(宾)] + 动 + 了/过/着 + 宾 + 了 + 吗/呢/吧/啊

That's what I've figured out so far. It might not be that accurate.